# GetRawData function?

Tags: vb.net, measurement-studio

I want to get the raw data from an analogwaveform channel and simply load it into an array of Doubles.  Here is what I have:

```
Dim data() As AnalogWaveform(Of Double)
    Dim dataToFilter() As Double

    For Each WaveformGraph In WFGS
        dataToFilter(i) = data(i).GetRawData() 'Value of Type '1-dimensional array of Double' cannot be converted to 'Double'.
        WaveformGraph.PlotWaveformAppend(data(i))
        i = i + 1
    Next
```

Can someone please help me with the line of code in question.  I need to get the raw data from the analogwaveform so that I can apply a filter to it before I stream it to a Waveformgraph.

Thanks.

Comment: You are declaring your `AnalogWaveform(Of Double)`, but it is never assigned. Right after you fix your current problem, you'll run into a `NullReferenceException`. It needs to come from somewhere. Also, I believe your `data()` (an array) should really be just `data`.

Comment: I'm going with the assumption the OP has given us relevant fragments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim data() As AnalogWaveform(Of Double)
Dim dataToFilter As New List(Of Double())

Dim i As Integer = 0
For Each WaveformGraph In WFGS
    dataToFilter.Add(data(i).GetRawData())
    WaveformGraph.PlotWaveformAppend(data(i))
    i += 1
Next
```

Comment: Your error tells me that "GetRawData()" returns an array of Double.  I've therefore set dataToFilter up as a List of Double arrays, in other words each element in the List is an array of type Double.